# Zshell special variable for previous command's output

Tags: shell, command-line-arguments, zsh

What is the special variable that stores that previous command's output in a zshell?  For example, if I did:

```
$ which zsh
  something
```

Instead of copying the output 'something', is there a way to get the output by way of a special variable?

I know I could use `$_` to get the previous command that was called, is there something similar?

Answer (score 4):

You could just wrap `$_` in `$()` to execute it again I suppose

```
$ which zsh
/bin/zsh
$ echo $($_)
/bin/zsh
```

Not sure if there's a variable that holds that output without re-running the command though...

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thanks. Instead, I use `find . -i 'FILENAME'`, then I use `vim $($_)`, since it usually finds one file.

Comment: Actually, I found out using `xargs` is more convenient `find . -i 'FILENAME' | xargs vim `